# Post-increment and pre-increment operator in C

Tags: c, post-increment, pre-increment

Why is k not getting incremented whereas,i and j are getting incremented in the same expression.And i also want to know what is the output of the program.I am getting the output as
-2 3 1 0

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
 int i=-3, j=2, m, k=0;
 m=++i && ++j || ++k;
 printf("%d %d %d %d", i, j, m, k);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The logical or, `||` short-circuits, and after

```
++i && ++j
```

the value of the entire expression is determined, so the right operand of the `||` isn't evaluated.

```
m=++i && ++j || ++k;
```

is parenthesized `m = (++i && ++j) || ++k;` since the `&&` has higher precedence than the `||`.

The short-circuiting of the logical operators means that the right operand is only evaluated when the evaluation of the left has not yet determined the final result, for `||` that means the right operand is only evaluated if the left evaluated to 0, and for `&&`, the right operand is only evaluated if the left evaluated to a nonzero value.

So first `++i && ++j` is evaluated, and for that, first `++i` is evaluated. `i` had the value `-3` before, so `++i` evaluates to `-2`, which is not 0, hence the `++j` is evaluated too. `j` had the value `2` before, so `++j` evaluates to `3`, which is again nonzero, and thus `++i && ++j` evaluates to 1 (true). Since the left operand of the `||` is not zero, its result is already determined (to be 1), and the right operand isn't evaluated, thus `k` remains unchanged and `m` is set to 1.

Answer (score 6):

If the item on the left of an `||` condition evaluates to true, there is no point evaluating the right hand side since the OR condition is already satisfied. That is why the `++k` is not being evaluated

Answer (score 1):

These operators are known to be short-circuited operators. So, if the expression `++i && ++j` is true, it does not evaluate `k` (we know the value of the expression regardless to the value of `k`).

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with order precedence. Anytime a logical OR is executed, it will stop if the first operand is true, which in this case is j.

Answer (score 0):

The logical operator `||` works like this: if first condition is true then the second one is not evaluated.

So first `(++i && ++j)` checks.  It returns true, so after it `||` is not evaluated.  Thus, the value of k is not increased.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int add(int);
void main()
 {
    int i=3,k,l;
    clrscr();
    k= add(++i);
    l=add(i++);
    printf("i=%d k= %d  l=%d",i,k,l);
     getch();
 }
 int add(int ii)
 { 
   ++ii;
   return(ii);
 }

/*th eoutput is 
5    
5
5     can anyone expalin how? */
```

Answer (score -1):

#include"stdio.h"

#include"conio.h"

main()

{

int rmv=10,vivek=10;

clrscr();

rmv++;//this post incremant means incremant next step 10+1

//rmv+1 and rmv++ both are same

printf("1.rmv++=%d\n",rmv);//value is 10

printf("2.rmv++=%d\n",rmv++);//the value is increment 11

++vivek;//this pre increment means first increment the value so,1+10=11

printf("1.\t++vivek=%d\n",vivek);////++vivek and 1+vivek both are same

printf("2.\t ++vivek=%d",++vivek");

getch();

}

Comment: The pre increment is firft increment value(++rmvivek) and The post increment is next step increment value(rmvivek++)